# Sympy cannot evaluate an infinite sum involving gamma functions

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I am using Sympy to evaluate some symbolic sums that involve manipulations of the `gamma` functions but I noticed that in this case it's not evaluating the sum and keeps it unevaluated.

```
import sympy as sp
a = sp.Symbol('a',real=True)
b = sp.Symbol('b',real=True)
d = sp.Symbol('d',real=True)
c = sp.Symbol('c',integer=True)
z = sp.Symbol('z',complex=True)
t = sp.Symbol('t',complex=True)
sp.simplify(t-sp.summation((sp.exp(-d)*(d**c)/sp.gamma(c+1))/(z-c-a*t),(c,0,sp.oo)))
```

I then need to lambdify this expression, and unfortunately this becomes impossible to do.

With Matlab symbolic toolbox however I get the following answer:

**Matlab**

```
>> a=sym('a') 
>> b=sym('b');
>> c=sym('c')
>> d=sym('d');
>> z=sym('z');
>> t=sym('t');
>> symsum((exp(-d)*(d^c)/factorial(c))/(z-c-a*t),c,0,inf)
ans = 
(-d)^(z - a*t)*exp(-d)*(gamma(a*t - z) - igamma(a*t - z, -d))
```

The formula involves lower incomplete gamma functions, as expected.
Any idea why of this behaviour? I thought sympy was able to do this summation symbolically.

Comment: But in MATLAB you are neither "lambdyfiying" the function.

Comment: Yes, the Matlab was only an example to show that the summation can be done.

Comment: So whats the question? You want sympy to evaluate to the same as MATLAB? why? why is "imposible to do"? can you expand on what is exactly your problem? Replicating MATLAB should not necessarily need to be your objective.

Comment: @AnderBiguri The goal is to evaluate the sum in closed form. Matlab demonstrates this is mathematically possible. The question is how to do it with SymPy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your code with SymPy 1.2 results in

```
d**(-a*t + z)*exp(-I*pi*a*t - d + I*pi*z)*lowergamma(a*t - z, d*exp_polar(I*pi)) + t
```

By the way, `summation` already attempts to evaluate the sum (and succeeds in case of SymPy 1.2), subsequent simplification is cosmetic. (And can sometimes be harmful).

The presence of `exp_polar` means that SymPy found it necessary to consider the points on the Riemann surface of logarithmic function instead of regular complex numbers. ([Related bit of docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#polar-lift)). The function `lower_gamma` is branched and so we must distinguish between "the value at -1, if we arrive to -1 from 1 going clockwise" from "the value at -1, if we arrive to -1 from 1 going counterclockwise". The former is `exp_polar(-I*pi)`, the latter is `exp_polar(I*pi)`.

All this is very interesting but  not really helpful when you need concrete evaluation of the expression. We have to unpolarify this expression, and from what Matlab shows,  simply replacing `exp_polar` with `exp` is a correct way to do so here.

```
rv = sp.simplify(t-sp.summation((sp.exp(-d)*(d**c)/sp.gamma(c+1))/(z-c-a*t),(c,0,sp.oo)))
rv = rv.subs(sp.exp_polar, sp.exp)
```

Result: `d**(-a*t + z)*exp(-I*pi*a*t - d + I*pi*z)*lowergamma(a*t - z, -d) + t`

There is still something to think about here, with complex numbers and so on. Is `d` positive or negative? What does raising it to the power `-a*t+z` mean, what branch of multivalued power function do we take? The same issues are present in Matlab output, where `-d` is raised to a power.

I recommend testing this with floating point input (direct summation of series vs evaluation of the SymPy expression for it), and adding assumptions on the sign of `d` if possible.

Comment: Thank you, apparently it was the old sympy version that couldn't evaluate the sum. Anyway, d is a positive real